# Adding to a view of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 0])
>>> a[[0, 0, 1, 1]] + [1, 2, 3, 4]
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[[0, 0, 1, 1]] += [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a
array([2, 4])
```

I understand that `a[[0, 0, 1, 1]]` returns a view of `a`, whose first two elements point to `a[0]` and last two elements point to `a[1]`. Now what if I want to get `a = [3, 7]`? Which is to say, what is the easiest way to accomplish the following?

```
a = [0, 0]
indices = [0, 0, 1, 1]
values_to_add = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in indices:
    a[i] += values_to_add[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into `np.add.at`

```
>>> np.add.at(a, [0,0,1,1], [1,2,3,4])
>>> a
array([3, 7])
```

Please note that often `np.add.at` can be replaced with `np.bincount` to gain a considerble speedup.

Finally, advanced indexing does not return views but copies. Assignment, however, is a different matter still. It wouldn't be very useful, if the assignment were made to a copy...

Comment: Thank you! I feel very dumb right now... In my defense, this doc is really hard to find: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html

Comment: @MichaelMa No need to feel bad about it. It's not a stupid question.